# Problems testing Office Add-In with an already Existing Web API project

Tags: office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have a Web API service that is tested and working well.  In a separate project I have an Outlook Web Add-In.  The UI is working just fine.  Now, I would like to make calls to the Web Service I've created.

The Web API project launches IIS (using SSL)
I've copied (copy/paste) the Office Add-In folders to what would be the root folder ... (at least I think I have the web root folder)

After launching the Web Service from Visual Studio, I run OWA and side load my Add-in.  The right Icon appears.  When I click on one of the commands in the drop down, nothing happens.  Chrome's debugger doesn't show any messages that would indicate that my Add-in has been called.  No errors.

Comment: To clarify, was the add-in working when the Web API wasn't running, but after enabling the Web API, the add-in doesn't load? Does the add-in use a task pane add-in command? If so, when selecting the add-in in OWA, the task pane should open, even if the add-in doesn't load successfully. In the Network tab of the Chrome debugger, you should see a request to the SourceLocation URL in the add-in's manifest. The status of this request will indicate whether the browser could load the add-in URL from your web server.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT
I think my problem was fatigue.  Over the weekend we "duct taped" a solution together to get things running on our Dev Server.  This morning, I walked in and I restored the URL I was using in the Manifest file several days ago to try and see what exactly went wrong.  NOW EVERYTHING WORKS.

I'll add getting rest, to my REST training.   :D

Thanks for the response anyway.  I'm not entirely sure, why it's working now ... but I'm happy that it is.